# How can I use Firebase on Google App Engine with multiple Services?

Tags: python, python-2.7, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

I have a GAE app on Python 2.7 (please don't ask why) with 2 services: UI & API (ie I use `dispatch.yaml` to deploy multiple services, each in their on subfolders with their own `app.yaml`).  I have an API endpoint to create signed URLs for the UI front end to use to upload files to GCS.  As a security layer, I want verify users on the API using the same system that the UI uses: Firebase.

On both the UI and API, I have a helper function which:

1. Loads Firebase session cookie [per Firebase Admin Setup docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk)
2. Verifies it and extracts "claims" (info about the authenticated user)
3. UI/API then use claims to handle rest of web request/response

However, even with identical code in both UI and API (and identical settings in `app.yaml`) which are both part of the same GAE Project, Firebase throws an error in the API when calling `auth.verify_session_cookie(session_cookie, check_revoked=True)`, yet works like a champ in UI code.

## The Setup:

Here are the relevant parts of each files found in both UI and API Services' code subfolders

### app.yaml

```
# The Service names are set as appropriate in respective service app.yaml's:
# service: api
# service: default
...
env_variables:
  # Replace with your Firebase project ID.
  FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: 'my-rad-project'
  GCLOUD_PROJECT: 'my-rad-project'  # this env var doesn't seem to be necessary to set to make Firebase work on UI
```

### main.py

UI sets the cookie in code shown later.  This code here checks the cookie and extracts claims if able:

```
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
...
from firebase_admin import auth, initialize_app # This must go after the monkeypatch()
default_app = initialize_app()  # "[DEFAULT]"
...
def get_claims():
    session_cookie = request.cookies.get(COOKIE_NAME)
    # Verify the session cookie. In this case an additional check is added to detect
    # if the user's Firebase session was revoked, user deleted/disabled, etc.
    decoded_claims = auth.verify_session_cookie(session_cookie, check_revoked=True)
    return decoded_claims
```

There's also a flask endpoint to set the cookie `COOKIE_NAME` from the `idToken` provided by firebase.  This only exists in the UI Service, but it's hosted on the same subdomain as the API (the API endpoints simply have `/api` starting their URLs)

```
@app.route('/sessionLogin', methods=['POST'])
def session_login():
    id_token = request.json['idToken']
    # To ensure that cookies are set only on recently signed in users, check auth_time in
    # ID token before creating a cookie.
    try:
        decoded_claims = auth.verify_id_token(id_token, check_revoked=True)
        # Only process if the user signed in within the last 5 days.
        if time.time() - decoded_claims['auth_time'] < 5 * 24 * 60 * 60:
            expires_in = datetime.timedelta(days=5)
            expires = datetime.datetime.now() + expires_in
            session_cookie = auth.create_session_cookie(id_token, expires_in=expires_in)
            response = jsonify({COOKIE_NAME: session_cookie})
            response.set_cookie(
                COOKIE_NAME, session_cookie, expires=expires, httponly=True, secure=True, domain='.my.domain')
            return response
        # User did not sign in recently. To guard against ID token theft, require
        # re-authentication.
        err = 'Recent sign in required'
        log.error(err)
        return abort(401, err)
    except ValueError:
        err = 'Invalid ID token'
        log.error(err)
        return abort(401, err)
    except Exception as e:
        # Session revoked. Force user to login.
        err = "Firebase exception getting claims: {}".format(e)
        log.error(err)
        return abort(401, err)
```

### The Errors

When I send a web request to the API endpoint which handles the GCS signature, it first calls `get_claims()` then throws this error:

```
The credential used to initialize the SDK has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for details on how to initialize the Admin SDK with appropriate permissions (INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION).
```

### Fixes I Tried

I followed the [Firebase docs for setting it up for multiple apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-multiple-apps), thinking that since my UI is the "default" Service in my GAE app, maybe I needed to initialize the API app which is called the "api" Service in my `app.yaml`.  This didn't help:

```
# In API's main.py
default_app = initialize_app()
api_app = initialize_app(name='api')
```

I then used [Google's own Auth layer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine) which is supposed to work with Firebase:

```
# API's main.py
from google.oauth2.id_token import verify_firebase_token
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

HTTP_REQUEST = Request()
...
# Change 1 line in `get_claims()` like so:
decoded_claims = verify_firebase_token(session_cookie, HTTP_REQUEST)
```

This led to a new error: `Certificate for key id asdf1234 not found.`
I found a [seemingly related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906807/google-sign-in-certificate-for-key-id-xxxx-not-found-when-using-google-auth-p/56742836#56742836) but his solution didn't work (I have a webpage, not an Android app, and even if I try in a different browser forcing me to log in with Google into a new session, the server still throws the same error)

All along the way, the UI works just fine to run `get_claims()`.  What do I need to do to use Firebase authentication on my API Service using a cookie set by my UI Service, both of which are on the same subdomain and have the same environment variables set in their `app.yaml` files?

Comment: Hi @hamx0r ! Thanks for the detailed question! I think there is two paths for you to follow here: initially, checking this documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors), indicates that you will need to configure your Firebase Admin SDK for usage as clarified [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional). Could you please give it a try? After that, in case this still don't help, I would recommend you to reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support), for them to better assist you.